# Is there a Latin, or English, phrase or acronym for "in summary"?

Tags: single-word-requests, latin, acronyms, email

Is there something similar to *TLDR* that can be used in professional emails and messages?

Comment: It might help if you were to explain what "TLDR" means! Not everyone knows or is a mind reader. I've never seen it before!

Comment: Too Long; Didn't Read. It has changed its meaning of late: rather than being a *response* to a long missive, it is now used to introduce a summary passage.

Comment: Wiktionary defines *[TLDR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR)* and various similar forms as “(Internet) too long; didn't read. Used to indicate that one didn't read the whole text or to indicate that what follows is a summary of the overly long text”.

Comment: This is just my being curious, but what's wrong with "in summary?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think phrases or labels like *In short* or  *In brief* may serve better, but if you insist on Latin, *[in nuce](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_nuce)* means  “in a nutshell; briefly stated”.

Comment: If he insists on Latin, I'm not sure this is the correct site.

Comment: @KitFox: the Latin phrase, if used commonly in English, is, de facto, English usage even if from Latin directly. So the question must be answered as though it was asked about Latin _in_ English.

Comment: *Paucis verbis* (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paucis%20verbis) seems to fit the headline question better.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something similar to TLDR that can be used in professional emails and messages?

Depending on context and content, ***abstract*** or ***executive summary*** could be appropriate headings, especially if placed at the beginning of the document. ***Summary*** and ***conclusion*** are often used at the end of a document.